# iteration fails over sorted array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, loops

I have the following method that sorts a list of binding source indices and puts their corresponding objects into an array. I have also tried using `Array.Sort()` and neither works, the code within the foreach loop never gets called. I have tested that the variable `int[] indices` is neither empty nor null.

```
internal void Foo(int[] indices)
{
    var bar = new Object[indices.length];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (int index in indices.OrderBy(x => x))
    {
        // this block never gets called
        bar[i] = BindingSource[index];
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could golf this into a LINQ "oneliner": `var bar = (from i in indices order by i select BindingSource[i]).ToArray()` - maybe that will clear up the bug. (That said, my guess is the reason is that `indices` is empty, just maybe not in the calls that you debugged.)

Comment: How are you verifying that it never gets called?  In the debugger?

Comment: Using your code I was able to trace in the `foreach` as long as indices contains at least one element.  If you're still having the problem, there's something you're not including with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `OrderBy` was not returning the sorted array, as I had assumed it did. The following is my solution.

```
internal void Foo(int[] indices)
{
    var bar = new Object[indices.Length];
    int i = 0;
    indices = indices.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
    foreach (int index in indices)
    {
        // now this block gets called
        bar[i] = BindingSource[index];
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now though, the `ToArray()` only takes memory and time. Leave that out and the only difference is better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var bar = indices.OrderBy(x => x).Select(x => BindingSource[x]).ToArray();
```

But I think that your code should work though I think that you could improve it using a for-loop instead of a foreach.

```
internal void Foo(int[] indices)
{
    var bar = new Object[indices.Length];
    indices = indices.OrderBy(x => x);
    for(int i = 0; i < indices.Length; i++)
        bar[i] = BindingSource[indices[i]];    
}
```

Another thing, you should get sure that the `indices.Length` doesn't equal `0` so I think that indices is empty.

**PS :** C# is case-sensitive so `indices.length` in your code should be `indices.Length` .